# In Objective-c how do I make a method that's accessible by all child class, but not accessible publicly

Tags: objective-c, inheritance

Say i create a viewController. Then I want to create another viewController that's like the first one. Looks like a job for inheritance.

However, many of the task of the originalViewController are private methods and I want to minimize public interface.

If I declare those methods public then well, the objective of keeping private things private is not achieved.

If I declare those methods private, then the child class do not know those methods.

If I create a special .h files for the child class, it'll be awkward.

So what's the industry standard way of doing this sort of thing anyway?

In C++ we would use protected methods or function to accomplish this right?

Update:

I put

```
#import "BGGoogleMap+protected.h"

@implementation BGGoogleMap ()

@end
```

It doesn't work. It asks for identifier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to what Catfish_Man suggests, you can make categories on your class that only your subclasses have access to. [Here are the docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/chapters/occategories.html) for how to do that. Basically, you just create a new interface for your class and put any private methods in there. Like this:

```
@interface MyClass (MyClass_Private)
// Method declarations
@end
```

Put those in Foo_Internal.h, and include Foo_Internal.h in your subclasses, but don't make it public.

Comment: Take a look at `UIKit/UIGestureRecognizerSubclass.h` if you want an example of this from Apple.

Comment: UIKit/UIGestureRecognizerSubclass.h define UIGestureRecoqnizer. ANY classes that  use the subclass will include that whole class. I think I am missing.

Comment: Well, sure, because UIGestureRecognizer is in the public headers. But I think rob was suggesting that the technique is the same, but to put them in private headers.

Answer (score 3):

Splitting the header into Foo.h and Foo_Internal.h sounds like the best way to go.

Comment: Do you actually do this? Also can one class have different .h files?

Comment: Yes I do, and yes you can. You declare the rest of it as @interface Foo (), yes, with the empty parens. See http://www.friday.com/bbum/2009/09/11/class-extensions-explained/

Comment: I thought class extension can only be declared in the .m file?

Comment: .m files have no special abilities relative to .h files

Comment: So one object can be declared in various different files?