# Provide access to the private method that are defined in base class

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have found this [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13596909/in-objective-c-how-do-i-make-a-method-thats-accessible-by-all-child-class-but), but I think I am a little confused.

So as I understood if I use category in my BaseDataHandler.m:

```
@interface STDataHandler (STDataHandlerPrivateMethods)

- (void)syncDataWithServer:(NSDictionary *)params;

@end
```

the method syncDataWithServer will not be found in the child for example `DataHandlerPlayer.m`.

So my question is how I can provide this method for the child but hide for other classes. If I put this method to `@interface` in `BaseDataHandler.h` it will be a public one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take that category definition for your interface and put it in a file called STDataHandler_private.h.  Then import STDataHandler_private.h in your child class's .m file.

In theory some other class could import your "private" header and access that method too... so don't do that.  ;)

Comment: ok the one way as I understood it is just create one additional header correct?

Comment: Yes.  The other answerer is technically correct, but using a separate "private" header approximates what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that. Objective-C does not separate between private and protected as Java does.

Comment: oh, bad news =) but in any case thanks for the answer, I think creation some additional file it is not good, because as Nicholas said we can import sometimes this file and get access to the private method as well as we can use public for example